# Derivative of $f\left(x\right)=\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of $f\left(x\right)=\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)$ by only using the formula $\arctan\left(u\left(x\right)\right)'=\frac{u'\left(x\right)}{u\left(x\right)^2+1}$. I don't honestly understand this formula, here are however my calculations. Is this the right way to find the derivative? And how do I proceed?

$$\LARGE
\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}}\cdot \frac{\left(1-x\right)-\left(1+x\right)}{x^2-2x+1}}{\frac{x+1}{1-x}+1}
$$

I also appreciate if you can explain what that "formula" exactly is.

Comment: Check chain rule.

Comment: @NightWish Don´t You mean $(\arctan(u(x)))'=...$ in the second line?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576789/injectivity-and-range-of-arctan-left-sqrt-frac1x1-x-right/2576893#2576893  before differentiation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well done! Your answer is correct. To make it a bit more presentable, let us simplify this further to get: $$f’(x) = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}{2}\times \frac{-2x}{x^2-2x+1}}{2}(1-x)$$ $$=-\frac{(1-x)^{\frac32}}{2\sqrt{1+x}(x^2-2x+1)}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

---

**EDIT:**

Well, you have your derivative calculated wrong, it should be $$\frac{(1-x)-(1+x)(-1)}{x^2-2x+1} = \frac{2}{x^2-2x+1}$$
So, removing the minus sign, we have: $$f’(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, however on my papers, I need to come to the solution as $f'\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and I don't understand if there is any difference between that one and this.

Comment: The solution given in the answer is wrong...no matter what WA says

Comment: @Rohan It still is wrong...and the link you provide of WA has the arctan of the inverse expression within the square root...

Comment: @DonAntonio Edited.

Comment: It's a tricky derivative this one...and it is very easy to get confused and write $\;\frac{1-x}{1+x}\;$ inside that square root....

Comment: Ah, now is fine. That tricky derivative $\;(-1)\;$ of the denominator can really confuse.

Comment: @NightWish Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Oh I see, thank for letting me know about that mistake and also thanks a lot @DonAntonio for the quick responses. I understand this problem now fully. :)

Answer (score 3):

The chain rule says that, if $u$ is some differentiable function of $x$, the composition $\,\arctan u(x)$ has derivative:
\begin{align}
\bigl(\arctan u(x)\bigr)'_x&=\bigl(\arctan u(x)\bigr)'_u\cdot u'_x(x)=\frac1{1+u^2(x)}\cdot u'_x(x)=\frac1{1+\smash[b]{\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}}}\cdot u'_x(x)\\
&=\frac12(1-x)u'_x(x).
\end{align}
Now $u(x)$ is itself a composition: $u(x)=\sqrt{v(x)}$, where $\,v(x)=\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}$, hence
$$u'_x(x)=u(x)'_v\cdot v'_x(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{v(x)}}\cdot\frac2{(1-x)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\cdot\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\frac1{\sqrt{(1-x)^2(1-x^2})},$$
so that, after simplifying,
$$f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Comment: Would you please explain what that "sub x" or "sub u" exactly means in $u(x)'_x$ or $u(x)'_u$ in this context?

Comment: @NightWish I think Bernard here uses that subindex to denote " the derivative with respect to $\;x\;$" . There's really no need to do that as we only have functions of one variable which is $\;x\;$ . It is useful when we deal with functions of several variables...

Comment: @DonAntonio: You're right. I added these indices to insist on w.r.t. what thederivative is calculated (a common,, though not correct, of the chain rule is $(f\circ u)'_x=f'_u\cdot u'_x$. It is as though there were temporarily several variables.

Comment: @Bernard Great point indeed. Thanks.+1

Answer (score 2):

For your convenience, you could first write

$$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac2{1-x}-1\implies\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'=\frac2{(1-x)^2}$$

Thus, with the aid of the chain rule:

$$\left(\arctan\sqrt\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)'=\frac1{1+\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\cdot\frac1{2\sqrt\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\cdot\frac2{(1-x)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{1-x}2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{1+x}}\cdot\frac2{(1-x)^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1+x}{1-x} = \frac{ (1-x)--(1+x)}{(1-x)^2}= \frac{2 }{(1-x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we need to do a $3-$ fold chain rule, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} f(g(h(x))) = h'(x) g'(h(x)) f'(g(h(x))).
\end{eqnarray*}
So in your case we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \right) = \frac{\frac{2 }{(1-x)^2} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} }}{1+ \frac{1+x}{1-x}} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Your differentiation of $\;\cfrac{1+x}{1-x}\;$ is wrong....you forgot that the derivative of the denominator is $\;-1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

The formula tells you how to compute the derivative of an $\arctan$ expression.

Let us first focus on $\arctan x=\tan^{-1}x$ and use the inversion formula.

$$y=\arctan x\iff x=\tan y$$ and

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{\dfrac{dx}{dy}}=\frac1{\dfrac1{\cos^2y}}=\frac1{\tan^2y+1}=\frac1{x^2+1}.$$

Now by the chain rule,

$$\left(\arctan u(x)\right)'=\frac{d\arctan u}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u'(x)}{u^2(x)+1}.$$